# Record Audio from an Android Phone on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, android, streaming

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro , Ventura OS. I have an audio captured through Dolby-on on a Samsung Android Phone. I could not export the audio file from the android phone but it only allows to playback on the phone. I want to convert the audio into m4a file and store it in my MacBook. Please share any inputs that I can follow to stream the audio from my Android phone and capture that as an audio input into my MacBook and save it as a m4a file in my MacBook. Is there any means to do using USB or Bluetooth mode to perform this task. I don't want any third-party apps (paid version) but any in-built or open-source tool that does this job will suffice.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://dolbyon.dolby.io/hc/en-us/articles/5410489858191-Saving-exporting-and-sharing Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes @Thinkr, ?I did try that option and export the audio file. After completing some 20% progress, it stops and throws an error "Error saving the file" and stops the process. I have lots of storage space. So i dont know what causes this issue. Hence I am trying to somehow capture that audio stream and record it in my laptop.